# ASP.NET DropDownList not refreshing after "display:none;"

Tags: c#, css, asp.net

guys.

I have a situation here. A DropDownList is inside a modal:

```
<div class="modal"><asp:DropDownList runat="server"></asp:DropDownList></div>
```

So, the page is created, a CSS code hide it:

```
.modal{display:none}
```

And after, when I need, I display it via bPopup (jQuery plugin):

```
$(".modal").bPopup();
```

The problem is when I hide it: it loses the ability to refresh when I send it to C# (code behind).

However, if I let it in default (display:block;), it works fine.

I tried to apply the "selected='selected'", which works the same way I said (yes to "block", no to "none").

Is there something I'm missing? Any property ASP.NET WebForms need to do it?

P.s.: I tested the code as the examples above, with the same problem.